# Can't build a Python Docker container on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, docker, bluez, pygobject, dbus-python

I have a backend Python project which I've been dockerizing sucessfully on my local machine. After several tries, it seems some Python packages (either [`dbus-python`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/) or [`PyGObject`](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) require some system packages to be built, so I use a Debian Docker image to be able to install those dependencies.

When building and running the image on my local machine (MacOS) using `docker compose up -d`, it works fine, installing the system packages, the Python packages, and building and running the docker containers successfully.

All in all the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# We use Debian to be able to install pygobject
FROM python:3.11-slim-bookworm

# Download latest listing of available packages:
RUN apt-get -y update
# Upgrade already installed packages:
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install the system packages which seem to be necessary for installing pygobject:
RUN apt-get -y install libdbus-glib-1-dev libgirepository1.0-dev libcairo2-dev

WORKDIR /backend

COPY ./requirements.txt /backend/requirements.txt

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /backend/requirements.txt

# Add backend folder to container
COPY ./ /backend

# Run the backend server on port 5000
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

However, when I do the same on a Raspberry Pi (`docker compose --build`), I get an error on the line `RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /backend/requirements.txt`:

```
Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
...
× Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
...
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
...
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /backend/requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

This is the error I also used to have on my local machine (`ninja` probably being a subdependency of either [`dbus-python`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/) or [`PyGObject`](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), before solving it by using a Debian image and installing the system dependencies. So I'm a bit confused:

**How come a docker build can produce an building error on one host machine and not one other?**

Comment: The architecture of the Pi is ARM, and certain packages fail to compile. My suggestion is to log on to the container up until the failing step and debug locally - then you might be able to come up with a step that works cross-platform.

Comment: I guess I'm confused with how Docker works fundamentally... I thought it was building those dependencies within the virtual architecture of the image, which was supposed to make it completely portable whatever the host architecture is.

Comment: No, containers are not virtual machines.  If you examine your base image on Docker Hub you see that it supports 7 different OS/Architectures (see https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags?page=1&name=3.11-slim-bookworm).  Some other image supports `linux/amd64` only, for example.

Comment: Understood. Feel free to post this as the answer.
By the way I solved this specific issue by adding the system package `cmake` to be installed.